# How would I say "From the mind of" in latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

I'm making a journal for my girlfriend and would like to put "from the mind of [name]" on the front page. Sort of a play on "ex libris". If that doesn't really work, or sounds odd, "[name]'s thoughts" or "thoughts from the mind of [name]" or similar would work too. Ex cogitationes?

Answer (score 5):

I would express "mind" here with *animus*.
Lewis and Short list the meanings 
"rational soul", "senses", "intellect", "mind", and "memory"
in their dictionary.
Another option would be *mens*, but I think the somewhat more emotional nuance of *animus* is a better fit for this purpose.

As *ex libris* is "from the books", "from the mind" would be ***ex animo***.
To make a complete title you would need the Latin genitive of the name or some other word of address.
There is no simple "of" in Latin, so forming the genitive is a bit more laborious.
Using *amica* ("female friend"), the title could be ***ex animo amicae***, "from the mind of [a/the] [female] friend".

If her name ends in *-a*, then to get the genitive you simply replace the *-a* by *-ae*.
(It is better to think this way than just adding an *-e* to the end. One of the reasons is that it works differently if the word ends differently.)
If, for example, the name is *Maria*, then you would have ***ex animo Mariae***.
If the name ends in something else, you should ask a separate question on this site for help with that specific name.

If you want to use *cogitationes*, it needs to go in the ablative case: *ex cogitationibus*.
This is certainly possible, but is more "from thoughts" than "from mind".

Comment: Thank you! So, if her name is say, Maria, ex animo Marie would work, right?

Comment: @Gremlet Almost! It'd be *Mariae* with two As. I added a paragraph on that to my answer.